# How to drop all not null constraints from a DB2 table

Tags: sql, db2, db2-luw

I would like to drop all not null constraints from all columns in a table in DB2 without having to specify each column name.

Ideally this would be a function, where I could pass a table name as a parameter. Going through sysibm.syscolumns to get the not null columns is perfectly fine.

Thanks!

EDIT:

A bit of background:

DB: DB2 LUW v11.1.0.0

OS: Linux, Debian (Debian 4.9.51-1 (2017-09-28)

I am creating a table from another table and need to import data into the newly created table. Unfortunately, the data to be imported sometimes does not have all the values which are needed for the not null columns, hence I have to remove all not null constraints before loading the data.

For Oracle, I have the following:

```
function f_remove_mandatory(p_tbname in varchar2) return boolean is
l_tbname         all_tab_columns.table_name%type;
l_AltTabTxt      varchar2(220);

cursor c_AlterDlTab (p_tablename in varchar2) IS
select column_name
from user_tab_columns
where table_name        = p_tablename
and nvl(nullable,'x') = 'N';
begin
    l_tbname := UPPER(p_tbname);
    for c1 in c_AlterDlTab (l_tbname) loop
        execute immediate 'ALTER TABLE ' || l_tbname ||' MODIFY ' || c1.column_name || ' NULL';
    end loop;
    return true;
    exception when others then return false;
end;
```

And need something similar for DB2.

Comment: Which Db2-server version?  Which operating-system runs Db2?

Comment: But why do you want to do that?!?

Comment: Hi, I have updated the original question. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to risk dirty data in your production table even temporarily?  Why not use a staging table (with or without constraints) ?

Comment: The new table is a staging table on a separate schema.

Comment: It should be possible to do this in a nearly identical manner with Db2 in a stored procedure.  Or, in Oracle compatibility mode, you may be able to run the code you have above.   *StackOverflow isn't a code-writing service*, so if you'd like to post what you've tried, what errors or problems you are having, someone can help more.

Comment: A native SQL-PL procedure can do it with Db2 LUW, although may be wise to have a single ALTER TABLE statement with multiple ALTER COLUMN clauses to avoid the reorg that current Db2 versions require after a certain number of ALTER TABLE actions on a single table.   In Oracle-emulation mode, present Db2 LUW versions don't appear to support Oracle-style ALTER TABLE ...MODIFY syntax so  even with Oracle-emulation mode some code changes are likely. In addition, there are several restrictions on Db2 LUW `ALTER TABLE...ALTER COLUMN...DROP NULL` syntax per IBM's documentation.